# Вылетает после етой строки FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); Решил сделать месенджер    и сделал все как написано в Assistant.Но приложение даже не запускается, сразу вылетает.

```
MainActivity

package com.example.demochat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp; import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void connect(){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connect();
    } }
```

> logcat-
>
> 2019-03-03 16:26:27.104 7208-7208/com.example.demochat
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.demochat, PID: 7208
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demochat/com.example.demochat.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.demochat. Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.demochat. Make sure to
>   call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.example.demochat.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:15)
>           at com.example.demochat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: а что в логах пишет?) там иногда встречается полезная информация :)

Comment: 16:23 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

16:23 Gradle build finished in 3 s 607 ms

Comment: мне кажется это не логи, у вас в android studio есть вкладка logcat и там должно при падении появляться куча красных строчек, иногда с указанием на проблемную строку в программе.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mslprr

Comment: ошибка в 15 и 24 строке вашего класса mainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте инициализировать приложение.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Также нужно что б было прописано использование плагина:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```